# How do you switch between multiple backgrounds in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was practicing using the pygame package in python by making a graphics oriented game and in my game, I want to switch between multiple backgrounds as the user progresses through it. For the example I am posting, the first background will be a black screen with 5 statements on it and my second background will be a room. However, I am unable to figure this out because whenever I try to run the code, the game window doesn't show anything. I can post my code for the while loop below for further clarification.

```
while running:
   screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

   first_line()
   second_line()
   third_line_1()
   third_line_2()
   fourth_line()
   fifth_line()

   sleep(10)

   screen.blit(background_room, (0, 0))

   pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and fix the indentation of the code. What do you mean "multiple backgrounds"? Where is an unchanging one being display by the code? Broadly speaking, you will need to store the background in a variable and change the value of that variable whenever you want the one displayed to change. The current value of the variable will also need to be referenced every time another frame is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would probably do it is something like

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Backround:
    FIVE_STATEMENTS = 0
    ROOM = 1

viewport_size = (800, 600)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(viewport_size)

    backround_room = pygame.Surface(viewport_size)
    # load the image...

    backround_statements = pygame.Surface(viewport_size)
    backround_statements.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # blit the five statements onto here

    backround_to_render = Backround.FIVE_STATEMENTS

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

        if backround_to_render == Backround.FIVE_STATEMENTS:
            # if the statements ever change, probably want to fill() and re-blit them on
            screen.blit(backround_statements, (0,0))

        elif backround_to_render == Backround.ROOM:
            screen.blit(backround_room, (0,0))

        else:
            print("Oh no!!!!!!!")

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```